# Unable to get Azure spatial anchors after creating them

Tags: azure, unity-game-engine, hololens, azure-spatial-anchors

I have a HoloLens project where I'm using Azure spatial anchors to sync a multiplayer environment. I followed the MRTK tutorials that have the lunar rover to help get me started. Today I was working and my app failed to locate the anchor on other devices after the main device created one.

I launched the lunar rover demo I made in the tutorial that used the same Azure resource, and it too is having the same issue where other connected devices get stuck finding the anchor forever.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/tutorials/mr-learning-sharing-05

I can confirm both of the apps had working anchors before. What would cause this to happen? I made no code changes that should reflect this behaviour. Could the Azure service have issues? Not sure why I can successfully start a session, create an anchor, but then fail to find it.

In the MRTK demo, here is a HoloLens 1 creating and sharing the anchor.
[image]

And here is a HoloLens 2 receiving the shared anchor ID, and trying to locate it.
It's been stuck trying to find the anchor for 5 minutes with no error or message.
[image]

Comment: I want to add a note, that I rebuilt the tutorial. I followed it every step of the way, and it still fails to locate Azure spatial anchors.

I'm trying to do all my due deligence to solve this mystery.
I just want to know who else has run into this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had exactly the same issue on my project you must upgrade your Azure Spatial Anchors SDK to the latest version or at least to 2.7.0 version.

All version bellow were discontinued since 3rd of Febuary 2021 (https://github.com/Azure/azure-spatial-anchors-samples/releases/tag/v2.7.0):

- **This SDK 2.7.0 release contains an important change. All clients are
  required to upgrade to 2.7.0 SDK or later before February 3, 2021.
  Any client application on earlier versions of Azure Anchors SDK will
  not be able to connect to the ASA service starting February 3, 2021.**

Comment: Yup. Got it. I somehow missed the memo.